# Is it possible to fit an internal dropper to 2x bike

Tags: mountain-bike, xc

I'm thinking about getting a XC bike and fitting a dropper.

I've got my eyes on some of the cubes, ie 
https://www.cube.eu/uk/2017/hardtail/reaction/cube-reaction-gtc-2x-carbonnflashred-2017/

It's got a narrow seat post (27.2mm) and the only cheap dropper I can find to fit it needs to be internally routed. (http://www.chainreactioncycles.com/brand-x-ascend-27-2-cx-dropper-seatpost/rp-prod159175)

Is it going to be possible to internally route this , when the bike has a 2x not a 1x setup?

Comment: Depends how much depth in the seat post is required by that dropper post.  Whether the bike has 1/2/3 chainrings is mostly unrelated, unless the FD mount has somehow changed the space inside the seat tube.

Comment: @Criggie ok thanks, and is there likely to be space to internally route the 3 cables?

Comment: No idea sorry - looks like the cable is supposed to go into the BB area then back up the downtube from the inside.  Then get out onto the bars somehow?  See what answers the rest of the community come up with.

Answer (score 4):

Being able to route an internal dropper is nothing to do with 1x/2x, and more to do with if the frame manufacturer has provided the facility to do so.  There will usually be a dedicated port in the seat tube.

As demonstrated by this Canyon Spectral (picture linked from Pinkbike):
[image]

Comment: This is exactly correct. The only thing I would add is that it is unlikely in the extreme to be a facility provided on an XC hardtail.

Comment: @zenbike we are starting to see more and more droppers used by racers in the XC world cups, so we may see support for this start to come through when the manufacturers of the big teams (Scott, BMC, Cannondale, Trek, Specialized) produce their next iteration of frames.

Comment: I understand, and I agree, for the future. But for current bikes, it is still extremely unlikely to see On an XC frame.

Comment: Looks like it has it in the 2018 model. A shame because I want one in the sale!

Answer (score 2):

As an alterative to at least consider: There are dropper posts with a lever directly below the saddle without a remote and therefore no need to route a cable.

I have installed one of these (KS eTEN) on my ~20 year old hardtail.

Pros:

- Available for 27.2 mm
- No cable routing
- Easy to (un)install (For bikepacking I need a non-dropper post to attach my saddle bag on this bike. Each post has a saddle mounted, switching is a matter of seconds)

Cons:

- To operate one hand has to let go of the handle bar. Sounds easy but it just doesn't work on the trail. You have to plan ahead, and often, I don't.

It's a lot better than nothing, but just not the same as one with a remote.

Comment: Option 3, cheapest, lower your saddle manually before the run ?

Comment: These can still be operated while riding. It's just that when you realize you would need it _now_, it's too late. Another benefit is that the fully extended position is always the same, no need to mark/scratch the post to always get the height right.